# routing table incorrect after netplan static ip configuration

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing

Here is my netplan configuration on ubuntu-server 20.04.2 (virtual machine) (virtual box).

`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true

    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.175.40/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.175.1
  version: 2
```

The `enp0s3` interface is what provides internet to the virtual machine.

The `ip route` command output is below:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.175.1 dev enp0s8 proto static
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
192.168.175.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.175.40
```

In this output, if the 2nd line had come to the top, the virtual machine can access the internet properly. I deleted the 1st route (using `ip route del`) for achieving the same. But, after a reboot `ip route` still reverts to the above, and, thus the virtual machine cannot connect to the internet.

What is the solution here?

Comment: Don't declare 192.168.175.1 as a gateway.

Comment: So you've two default routes but ubuntu has no way of knowing which it should use..

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the additional subnet as static route (metric is overkill)

```
enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.175.40/24]
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.175.0/24
          via: 192.168.175.1
          metric: 0
```

Then to enable..

sudo netplan generate  (Check for errors)
sudo netplan apply  (make it live)